# Filtering a lot of entries using RecyclerView.Adapter

Tags: java, android, android-filterable

I have an `adapter` that extends `RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>` and implements `Filterable`.

My `getFilter()` implementation is:

```
@Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                mPersonListFiltered = (List<Person>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                List<Person> filtered = new ArrayList<>();

                if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                    results.count = mPersonList.size();
                    results.values = mPersonList;
                } else {
                    String name, email, constr = Utils.removeDiacriticalMarks(constraint.toString());
                    for (Person person : mPersonList) {
                        name =  Utils.removeDiacriticalMarks(person.getName().toLowerCase());
                        email = person.getEmail().toLowerCase();
                        if (name.contains(constr) || email.contains(constr)) {
                            filtered.add(person);
                        }
                    }
                    results.count = filtered.size();
                    results.values = filtered;
                }
                return results;
            }
        };
    }
```

I wish to filter my person list while typing. This works fine if my list size isn't greater than 1k, but if I scale it up to 5k, 10k, etc... it's starts to get laggy. And I understand why, for every person I'll have to check if contains a constraint for their name and email, it's awful.
But I was wondering if under this circumstances, a lot of entries, what would be the best implementation or alternative to achieve the same result, in other words, a fast filter method for a local gigantic list and "on-the-fly" typing.

Thanks.

Comment: you can create on method in adapter and when button click this method will returns one model and this method you must override when you define adapter 

This is best alternative solution of filterable in adapter

Answer (score 1):

You can *pre-filter* your `Person` entries.

You would create a `Map` of lists (actually `Set`s) for all of your single-character constraints, and maybe some multiple-character ones, too.

```
    Map<String, Set<Person>> mFilteredPersonMap  = new HashMap<>();
```

When you get the list of `Person`s for the adapter, add them to a set within the map:

```
                for (Person person : mPersonList) {
                    String name =  Utils.removeDiacriticalMarks(person.getName().toLowerCase());
                    for (char c : name.toCharArray()) {
                        if (Character.isWhitespace(c)) continue;
                        // you may want to skip other chars i.e. symbols
                        Set<Person> set = mFilteredPersonMap.get(Character.toString(c));
                        if (set == null) {
                            set = new HashSet<>();
                            mFilteredPersonMap.put(Character.toString(c), set);
                        }
                        set.add(person);
                    }
                    // do the same thing for email
                }
```

I used every letter in the name because you used `contains(constr)` in your original code.  My preference would be to search on characters after a word boundary (regex `"\\b(\\w)"`) and use those as keys for the map.

Then use the map as a first-level filter:

```
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            List<Person> filtered = new ArrayList<>();

            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                results.count = mPersonList.size();
                results.values = mPersonList;
            } else {
                String name, email, constr = Utils.removeDiacriticalMarks(constraint.toString());
                String key = constr.substr(0, 1);
                Set set = mFilteredPersonMap.get(key);
                if (set != null) {
                    // now you are looping through a smaller collection
                    for (Person person : set) {
                        name =  Utils.removeDiacriticalMarks(person.getName().toLowerCase());
                        email = person.getEmail().toLowerCase();
                        if (name.contains(constr) || email.contains(constr)) {
                            filtered.add(person);
                        }
                    }
                }
                results.count = filtered.size();
                results.values = filtered;
            }
            return results;
        }
```

Comment: This approach looks really interesting. Tomorrow I'll try it, thanks for your answer ;)

Comment: I didn't write the code in an IDE or anything, so don't be surprised if it has some problems.  Mostly I just wanted to convey the idea, which is simply to distribute your entries into smaller buckets before the filtering starts.  Let me know how it works out.